# Advanced Styling Laravel blade template using the <style> tag

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a paf.blade.php file, I've used html tags with some styling.
but  not all css rules I've specified have been applied to the pdf. For example, I want to apply these rules in order to customize my list numbering.

```
/* Numbered lists styling  like 1, 1.1, 2.2.1... */ ol li { display: block; }  
/* hide original list counter */
  ol>li:first-child {
    counter-reset: item;
  }

  /* reset counter */
  ol>li {
    counter-increment: item;
    position: relative;
  }

  /* increment counter */
  ol>li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 100%;
    right: 10px;
  }
```

I tried to use it, but I see no changes to the pdf which is made using blade.php, I have tried the same code on an HTML page (web page) and it is working. but if i copied it to the blade template changes is not applied.

Note: not all the CSS rules are not being applied but some of them like: before , : after, first child etc..

Here is what my blade file looks like:

```
<HTML>
<style type="text/css">
@page{
     /* some styling here */
}
     /* some styling here */
</style>
<body>
     /* html tags here */
</body>
</html>
```

I need to add styling to the blade.php